# React native app suddenly reloads bundle and crashes. What can trigger a bundle reload?

Tags: react-native

We are experiencing a production bug in which a React native app suddenly reloads the bundle and crashes.

Anybody knows what can trigger a bundle reload while using the app?

The last console log we're getting is:

> Running application "App" with appParams: {"rootTag":11}. **DEV** === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON

We've traced it to line 154 in AppRegistry.js (react-native@0.55.4):

```
/**
* Loads the JavaScript bundle and runs the app.
*
* See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html#runapplication
*/
```